# Snap Matrix4 rotation to 90, 180, 270, 360 degrees, Flutter

Tags: flutter, matrix, dart, rotation, transform

I'm currently using the [matrix_gesture_detector](https://pub.dev/packages/matrix_gesture_detector) package to scale, transform and rotate a `Transform` widget.

Everything works fine but to improve UX I would like to snap the widget at 90, 180, 270 or 360 degrees once the user rotates the widget close enough to said angles.

Edit: To clarify I would like the user to be able to freely rotate the widget, but snap into the nearest 90 degree rotation within whichever quadrant it is, once it gets close enough. 
Hence, the solution should detect that "closeness" and then act accordingly. [Please visit this link to see a GIF which shows the desired effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MMJQV.gif)

How can I achieve this?

Below is the code snippet

```
Widget transformContainer() {
Matrix4 matrix;
GlobalKey matrixDetectorKey = GlobalKey();

return MatrixGestureDetector(
  key: matrixDetectorKey,
  onMatrixUpdate: (m, tm, sm, rm) {
    setState(() {
      matrix = MatrixGestureDetector.compose(matrix, tm, sm, rm);
    });
  },
  child: Transform(
    transform: matrix,
    child: Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(24.0),
      width: 100.0,
      height: 200.0,
      color: Colors.teal,
    ),
  ),
);}
```

Comment: in `MatrixGestureDetector.compose(matrix, tm, sm, rm)` there is `rm` part which is 'rotation delta matrix` - simply do not use it if you want to use those 90, 180, 270 or 360 values

Comment: Sorry but always I find it difficult to understand your replies. The ```Matrix4.compose``` constructor requires a rotation delta matrix. How would I go about not using it and still achieving the result i want?

Comment: if you have rotated `matrix` (for example by 270 degrees) and want to snap it to that value so no further rotation is applied pass null instead of `rm`

Comment: Please see the edit and link in the question for more clarity on the desired solution. Responding with some code to follow would really be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For this to work, you have to check if the rotation of the matrix is closing in on a snapping point and rotate the Z-Axis to that point. I was able to write this code which works for this scenario. You may have to tune the `threshold` to adjust the "snappiness" to your taste.

import [vector_math](https://pub.dev/packages/vector_math) and use the following code:

`import 'package:vector_math/vector_math_64.dart' as vec;`

```
       onMatrixUpdate: (Matrix4 m, Matrix4 tm, Matrix4 sm, Matrix4 rm) {
          Matrix4 ogRm = rm.clone();
          double radian = MatrixGestureDetector.decomposeToValues(m).rotation;
          double degrees = vec.degrees(radian);

          double delta_0 = vec.absoluteError(degrees, 0);
          double delta_90 = vec.absoluteError(degrees, 90);
          double delta_180 = vec.absoluteError(degrees, 180);
          double delta_270 = vec.absoluteError(degrees, -90);
          double threshold = 4;

          if (delta_0 <= threshold) {
            rm.rotateZ(vec.radians(0) - radian);
          } else if (delta_90 <= threshold) {
            rm.rotateZ(vec.radians(90) - radian);
          } else if (delta_180 <= threshold) {
            rm.rotateZ(vec.radians(180) - radian);
          } else if (delta_270 <= threshold) {
            rm.rotateZ(vec.radians(270) - radian);
          }

          // update gesture matrix
          if (ogRm != rm) m = m * rm;

          setState(() {
            //transform your widget using this matrix
            matrix = m;
          });
        }
```

Note that 360 is the same as 0, so there's no need to check for it.

Answer (score 0):

```
MatrixGestureDetector(
        onMatrixUpdate: (m, tm, sm, rm) {
          setState(() {
            //270 is the angle
            m.rotate(m.getTranslation(), 270);
            matrix4 = m;
          });
        },
        child: Transform(
          transform: matrix4,
          child: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(24.0),
            width: 100,
            height: 200,
            color: Colors.teal,
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't solve the issue. I've updated the question to make it clearer what I'm trying to achieve. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will have the rotate function inside the library. this code will work for snapping to 0 degrees. Basically what I am doing is if the difference in rotation and x-axis is less than 0.2 radians, I snap to 0 degrees while keeping the rotation in a separate variable. When the user moves beyond this, I add this value again and keep rotating normally.

```
 Matrix4 _rotate(double angle, Offset focalPoint) {
    double toBeRotated = 0;
    var array = matrix.applyToVector3Array([0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]);
    Offset delta = Offset(array[3] - array[0], array[4] - array[1]);
    double rotation = delta.direction;
    deltaAngle = deltaAngle + angle;

  
    if ((rotation + deltaAngle).abs() > 0.2) {
      toBeRotated = deltaAngle;
      deltaAngle = 0;
    } else if (rotation != 0 && (rotation + deltaAngle).abs() <= 0.2) {
      toBeRotated = -rotation;
      deltaAngle = deltaAngle + rotation;
    } else {
      toBeRotated = 0;
    }
      var c = cos(toBeRotated);
    var s = sin(toBeRotated);
    
    var dx = (1 - c) * focalPoint.dx + s * focalPoint.dy;
    var dy = (1 - c) * focalPoint.dy - s * focalPoint.dx;

    //  ..[0]  = c       # x scale
    //  ..[1]  = s       # y skew
    //  ..[4]  = -s      # x skew
    //  ..[5]  = c       # y scale
    //  ..[10] = 1       # diagonal "one"
    //  ..[12] = dx      # x translation
    //  ..[13] = dy      # y translation
    //  ..[15] = 1       # diagonal "one"
    return Matrix4(c, s, 0, 0, -s, c, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, dx, dy, 0, 1);
  }
```

Comment: This is an interesting answer, but I couldn’t figure out where that deltaAngle variable comes from. There isn’t any global variable called deltaAngle either in MatrixGestureDetector. Where is it?

Comment: @Daniele I declared it on my own.